# Error in render: "ReferenceError: h is not defined"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jsx

All of a sudden I started getting an error from a couple of JSX components. At what point this problem arose, I do not know, so I cannot say what caused it.

It all started when I started getting an error from `render()`. I fixed it by adding `h` — `render(h)`.

Then I started getting error from methods in `computed`. For example, I have code like this:

```js
audioComponent() {
  return(
    <audio autoPlay playsInline ref="audio" />
  )
}
```

And I'm getting error from it:

> Error in render: "ReferenceError: h is not defined"

I use this component in `render(h)`:

```
<div>
  {this.audioComponent}
</div>
```

Can you please tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`computed` functions don't get passed an `h` (aka `createElement`), only `render` does. You can use `computed` functions to return data but they can't return vdom.

If you want something that simply takes input and returns vdom, consider a [functional component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components) instead

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And for what reason everything worked for me earlier?

Comment: @Colibri I suspect you weren't using JSX in a `computed` before. This is never possible AFAIK

Comment: Seriously, it all worked for me in computed. I understand what this is about and now I am very surprised that everything worked. I haven't touched the code in those places for several months. Now I have moved these functions from computed to methods and passed the h parameter to them. This method came up. Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: @Colibri no problem, who knows, software is funny. Please consider marking answer as accepted for the other helpful people who filter for unanswered posts

Comment: I was waiting for SO to let me do this (time limit) :)

Comment: Oh, TIL there's a wait time for that :o